# How do you setup a load balanced environment with ASP.Net 5 (vNext) while using the DNX environment?

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx

#### Description

I am curious about how a DNX load balanced setup will work.  I am accustomed to working with an ARR (Application Request Routing)/Server Farm setup with IIS [like this](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-(arr)/http-load-balancing-using-application-request-routing).  Typically there is nothing done on the code side with the ARR/Server Farm setup.  However, with the cross platform support that DNX provides, while getting rid of IIS, this sort of load balanced setup seems like it will now need to be handled in the code.  Or at least in my case I would be responsible for code deploys as opposed to a Network Admin that would install updates.  The closest that I could find is [session management](https://github.com/aspnet/Session/).  Can you do load balancing with this, potentially, I just do not see it there yet.

#### Functional Impact

Decide to download a third party ARR, use MS ARR, or Role your own ARR?

#### What I need

I would like to keep this from "I like this best" responses as much as possible and see responses that are "Here is why you need this" or "Here is why I found this to work well".  I know that dnx is a new environment, but the experience of setting up LB servers in OSX and Linux is not.  With the move to cross platform, I do not expect that the MS ARR will work on OSX or Linux.  I am not very familiar with those OS's so I do not know where to begin.

#### Question(s)

1) Is the https://github.com/aspnet/Session/ project (or another project) expected to contain an ARR?

If no on 1

2) Is there an ARR that is cross platform (Windows, OSX, Linux)?

Comment: ARR to me just reads like another term for http load balancer. You can do this with hardware; if you want to do it in software you can try nginx or squid. They appear to be cross platform, but I have only used them on Linux.

Comment: @chuex Yes ARR is just an http load balancer.  I have also run across [F5](https://f5.com/glossary/load-balancer), it is helpful to have some options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no out-of-the-box load balancer for ASP.NET 5.

Your solution is the right one, add a load balancer in front of DNX. On Windows you can use IIS, on cross plat you can use something like [ngnix](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html)

Answer (score 1):

No changes and no support for in-app.

`ASP.NET 5` is not where this should be going. IIS will still exist and the [ARR module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) is a part of IIS itself. Not the app.

On the page itself it says:

> Works With: IIS 7, IIS 7.5, IIS 8, IIS 8.5, IIS 10

As for supporting different kind of servers? I don't see why not since the ARR module is basically just a reverse-proxy.

Nothing need to change. You can even compile to CoreCLR and have it hosted on a farm of Linux machines with Apache but have an IIS server with the ARR Module set in Reverse-Proxy to forward load balance the requests.